# Bash process id query

Tags: bash, pid

I just saw a code with a check in if as

```
 for x in `ps -ef | awk '{ print $2 }'`
    do
        if [ "$x" != "PID" ];then
        ----- do something -----
        fi
    done
```

May I know why do we need to have this check in if and what is it doing ?

Comment: Did you run the command, that generates the input to the `for` loop?

Comment: you can remove `if condition` by slightly modifying `awk` statement to `ps -ef | awk 'NR>1{print $2}'` . This will skip header.

Comment: Or, instead of using `-f` to print info you discard, just do `for x in $(ps -e -o pid=); do ...`

Comment: missed a silly thing...anyways thanks a lot everyone :)

Answer (score 2):

That check is added to skip the header part. you can remove whole if statement by modifying `awk` statement to skip first line.  To find out what header is run `ps -eaf |head -n 1` .

```
  for x in $(ps -ef | awk 'NR>1{ print $2 }')
    do
          --------Do something with $x---------
    done
```

Comment: Additional information: some implementations of `ps` have a flag to omit writing the header - consult your man page.  That could simplify the script, though at the cost of portability.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `ps -ef` you will notice, that it will print a header:

```
     UID     PID    PPID  TTY        STIME COMMAND
[...]
```

the check skips the header.

Answer (score 1):

`ps -ef | awk '{ print $2 }'` outputs' as below; the first line is PID, so if statetement is used exclude PID line;

```
user@host:/tmp$ ps -ef | awk '{ print $2 }' | head
PID
1
2
3
5
7
8
9
10
```

you can also use this without if;

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in `ps -ef | awk '{ print $2 }' | grep -v PID`
do
    #----- do something -----
    echo $x
done
```